# Biometrics in Active Directory

Tags: windows-7, windows, active-directory, fingerprint, biometrics

Is it possible to implement Biometrics as a form of login with Active Directory in a Windows Server 2008 R2 set-up with Win7 clients?

I.e. a user roams freely among computers on the domain and simply 'swipes' to login.

If so can your answer in include possible techniques and technologies to do so. We'd like to minimise the use of `niche` third-party software please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463089?ppud=4) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759228.aspx) mention Biometrics integrated into Windows logon. The times i've used it before (mostly HP Laptops running XP) it worked well standalone, but I was asked to disabled it as the software encountered removes the Windows logon prompt and replaces it with 3rd party software (security issue).

From my experience (and the evolution of Windows XP -> 7) you would need to find 3rd party devices with drivers inbuilt to Windows 7, it would then not require 3rd party software to work.